# How to append the string at the beginning of array?

Tags: c

How do I append the string at the beginning of array? Is there any function to do that in C? Or should I create my own function?

```
strcat(a,".com") \\ if a = www.google it gets www.google.com after strcat() func.
```

But if array="google", how do i put www. at the beginning of it and make it www.google.com? We know using `strcat` we can append .com at the end but how to do it at the beginning? Let me know is there any function or should I develop my own function. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append "google" to "www" or use `snprintf`.

```
snprintf(large_enough_string, max_len, "%s.%s.%s", "www", "stackoverflow", "com");
```

Comment: @niko If you don't have it, use `sprintf` and check the size manually :-)